# Specifying time ranges for weekdays/weekends in queries

Tags: postgresql, date, time, days

I'm looking to pull the amount of requests that come in outside of working hours in the last 30 days, but I"m new to coding and not sure how to construct the query.

```
Where date > receivedat - interval '30 day'
```

However, operational hours are different on weekdays and weekends. How do I set the conditions to track requests coming in on specific days?

Comment: Are you passing date in parameter? After getting date, you need to get into table if that date is earlier than last 30 days, then you need to get requests from table according to hours(depends on week of day)? so what are those hours?

Comment: Sample data and expected result would help.

Comment: operational hours are 7 am - 10 pm on weekdays, and 8 am - 7 pm on weekends. part of my confusion stems from the downtime spanning two calendar days.

Comment: You need a calendar table, i.e. a table with 1 row for each day (or other time period), giving the relevant information such as start/end times, hours, whether public holiday and so on. Once you've populated that your query will be easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

here's a sample that might be close to what you need.

-- assumes  receivedat is datetime

SELECT * from your_table
where 
receivedat  > CURRENT_DATE - interval '30 day'
and NOT ( EXTRACT(DOW FROM receivedat ) between 1 and 5 and EXTRACT(HOUR FROM receivedat ) between 7 and 22 )
and NOT ( EXTRACT(DOW FROM receivedat ) between 6 and 7 and EXTRACT(HOUR FROM receivedat ) between 8 and 19 ) ;